# CSS Animation, working adding class, but not removing the class

Tags: css, css-animations

I've got this keyframe

```
@keyframes jump {
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10em, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 17.5em, 0);
  }
}
```

Then I have this class

```
.close.form_open {
  animation: jump .5s forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: jump .5s forwards linear;
}
```

I'm adding the class form_open with jQuery and when the class is added the animation is working properly, but when I remove the class (with jQuery), it doesn't show the animation. The element goes to the right position, but without any animation.
What am I missing?
My class close is empty

```
.close {

}
```

Thank you very much

**UPDATE:**  Added fiddle
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Bernardao/f2gwozgk/)

Comment: please specify the details of class `.close`

Comment: added, but it's empty as I said

Comment: Can you put the scenario on jsfiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/ 
It will be easier to see the issue

Comment: can you post all the relevant code in fiddle what you tried sofar?

Comment: It seems like you have another error in your code, this is what usually happens, but please, post some more code.

Comment: @Bernardao: Animations are not like transitions. They don't automatically have the reverse effect when the class is removed.

Comment: @Harry then how can code what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You could achieve the same result just using jQuery Toggle()
https://jsfiddle.net/f2gwozgk/7/

Comment: @NickRobins What I want to achieve is the animation and in your fiddle is not working any animation. In mine at least works when the text moves down

Comment: @Bernardao - Is this right? https://jsfiddle.net/f2gwozgk/12/   (UPDATED)

Comment: @Bernardao: You would have to create a reverse animation effect and add it to the element on the second click like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f2gwozgk/13/). I have changed some translate values but the approach would be same.

Comment: @Harry That's what I wanted, thank you. Create an answer and I would accept it

Comment: @NickRobins Yours works, but you're not using translate3d, I prefer translate3d because it uses GPU, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, animations are not like transitions. Transitions automatically do the reverse effect when the class (or property) is removed whereas animations would not do that by default.

To make it happen with animations, we should create a reverse effect of the animation and add it on every alternate click.

```js
$('#show_form').click(function() {
  $('.close').toggleClass('form_open form_close');
});
```

```css
/************** KEYFRAMES ********************/

@keyframes jump {
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes jump_close {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump_close {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
}
.close.form_open {
  animation: jump .5s forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: jump .5s forwards linear;
}
.close.form_close {
  animation: jump_close .5s forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: jump_close .5s forwards linear;
}
.form_open {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 espacio">
  <h4 id="show_form">
    Click here
  </h4>
  <div class="form_open">
    <div class="entrada_datos col-md-9 col-xs-7 col-lg-8">
      <form id="modifica_join" action="#" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          Some text
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row close form_close">
  Cerrar sesión
</div>
```

One drawback of the above code is that it would by default make the reverse animation happen on page load but that can be overcome by adding a counter based check (refer below snippet).

```js
var i = 0;
$('#show_form').click(function() {
  if (i == 0) $('.close').addClass('form_open');
  else $('.close').toggleClass('form_open form_close');
  i++;
});
```

```css
/************** KEYFRAMES ********************/

@keyframes jump {
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes jump_close {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump_close {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
}
.close.form_open {
  animation: jump .5s forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: jump .5s forwards linear;
}
.close.form_close {
  animation: jump_close .5s forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: jump_close .5s forwards linear;
}
.form_open {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 espacio">
  <h4 id="show_form">
    Click here
  </h4>
  <div class="form_open">
    <div class="entrada_datos col-md-9 col-xs-7 col-lg-8">
      <form id="modifica_join" action="#" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          Some text
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row close">
  Cerrar sesión
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the snippet working properly, better add the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Bernardao/f2gwozgk/18/

Comment: @Bernardao: Yea, sorry I had missed a class in the HTML. Fixed now :)